# Why this strange behaviour with laravel livewire image upload

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Laravel version : 8.x

livewire version : 2.x

I am working on a form for the student registeration for attendence management system project.

below is the image :

[image]

Now when i fill all the fields and when i select the photo to upload then all the other input fields go to blank

the code for the form is this :

```
<div class="create-student display-flex flex-direction-column flex-align-items-center flex-justify-content-flex-start">
    @livewire('header',['name' => 'Student Registeration Page','width'=> '70%','height' => '20%'])
    <form style="margin-top: 2%; padding-top: 1%" class="student-form display-grid " wire:submit.prevent="signUpUser" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <section class="name display-grid" >
            <div class="display-flex flex-direction-column flex-justify-content-center">
                <label for="FirstName">First Name <span style="color: red">*</span> :</label>
                <input wire:model.defer = "form.first_name" type="text" name="FirstName">
            </div>
            <div class="display-flex flex-direction-column flex-justify-content-center ">
                <label for="FirstName">Mid Name :</label>
                <input wire:model.defer = "form.mid_name" type="text" name="FirstName">
            </div>
            <div class="display-flex flex-direction-column flex-justify-content-center ">

                <label for="LastName">Last Name <span style="color: red">*</span> :</label>
                <input wire:model.defer="form.last_name" type="text" id="LastName" >
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="father-email display-grid ">
            <div  class="display-flex flex-direction-column flex-justify-content-center">
                <div>
                    <label for="FatherName">Email <span style="color: red">*</span> :</label>
                    <input wire:model.defer="form.email" type="Email" name="FatherName">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div  class="display-flex flex-direction-column flex-justify-content-center">
                <div>
                    <label for="FatherName">Father Name <span style="color: red">*</span> :</label>
                    <input wire:model.defer="form.father_name" type="text" name="FatherName">
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
        <section  class="roll-class display-grid flex-align-items-center ">
            <div class="display-flex flex-direction-column flex-justify-content-flex-end">
                <label for="RollNumber">Roll # <span style="color: red">*</span> :</label>
                <input wire:model.defer="form.roll_number" type="number" name="RollNumber">
            </div>
            <div class="display-flex flex-direction-column flex-justify-content-flex-end">
                <label for="Class">Class <span style="color: red">*</span> :</label>
                <input wire:model.defer="form.class" type="number" name="Class">
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="gender-profile display-grid flex-align-items-center">
            <div class="display-flex flex-direction-column flex-justify-content-flex-end">
                <label for="gender">Choose your gender <span style="color: red">*</span> :</label>
                <div class="">
                    <label style="display: inline;" for="male">male</label>
                    <input wire:model.defer="form.gender" style="" name="gender" type="radio" value="M">
                    <label style="display: inline" for="female">female</label>
                    <input wire:model.defer="form.gender" name="gender" type="radio" value="F">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="display-flex flex-direction-column ">
                <label for="photo">Profile Photo <span style="color: red">*</span> : </label>
                <input wire:model.defer="form.photo" type="file" name="photo">
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="password display-grid flex-align-items-center">
            <div style="width: 100%;height: 100%" class="display-flex flex-direction-row flex-align-items-center flex-justify-content-space-between">
            <div style="width: 50%; height: 100%" class="display-flex flex-direction-column ">
                <label for="password">Password <span style="color: red">*</span> : </label>
                <input  wire:model.defer.prevent="form.password"   type="password" name="password" required>
            </div>
            <button  type="submit" style="width: 40%;height: 100%; background-color: black;color: white">Register Student</button>
            </div>
        </section>

    </form>
</div>
```

the component's php class :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Student;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class Signup extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $form = [];

    public function hydrate(){
        $this->form['first_name']=null;
        $this->form['last_name']=null;
        $this->form['mid_name']=null;
        $this->form['email']=null;
        $this->form['password']= null;
        $this->form['father_name']=null;
        $this->form['class']=null;
        $this->form['roll_number']=null;
        $this->form['gender']=null;
        $this->form['photo']=null;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.student.signup')
            ->extends('layouts.app')
            ->section('content')
            ;
    }

    public function signUpUser(){
        dd($this->form);
    }
}
```

if you need anyother detail or something do tell me !!
Thank You!

Comment: What does your component look like? The PHP class. Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: i have checked . the php class is fine. i am adding the code for the component's php class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hydrate()` method gets run for every request. Since you are using `model:wire.defer`, none of the requests are made to the server instantly, they are queued up for the next request being fired (which apparently happens with the uploading of the photo).

From the Livewire v2 documentation,

> `hydrate()`: Runs on every request, after the component is hydrated, but before an action is performed, or render() is called

> `mount()`: Runs once, immediately after the component is instantiated, but before render() is called

Simply replace `hydrate()` with `mount()` - which only runs before the component is rendered for the first time - and that should take care of it.

```php
public function mount() {
    $this->form['first_name'] = null;
    $this->form['last_name'] = null;
    $this->form['mid_name'] = null;
    $this->form['email'] = null;
    $this->form['password']= null;
    $this->form['father_name'] = null;
    $this->form['class'] = null;
    $this->form['roll_number'] = null;
    $this->form['gender'] = null;
    $this->form['photo'] = null;
}
```

- [Livewire lifecycle hooks](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: ooohh at first i thought that using wire:model.defer won't cause such thing but  you are right

Comment: It has nothing to do with that you actually use `wire:model.defer`, that's just instructing Livewire to not send an AJAX request to the server until later. The problem was that you used the `hydrate()` lifecycle event to reset all the fields, instead of initializing them once through `mount()`.